# Types to add in field from database Agile Toolkit

Tags: php, user-interface, frameworks, atk4

I've discovering Agile Toolkit and I have problem with finding `addField('field')->type()`.
What kind of types could there be and where can I find them?
I need type 'set', but `addField('field')->type('set')` is not working.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

ATK4 is distributed with simple usable basic types which is limited to the following list:

- string
- date
- datetime
- text
- int
- real
- boolean
- password
- list

As for the `set` type, the nearest would be that of a `list` type.

example:

```
 $this->addField('month')->type('list')->caption('Month')
    ->listData(array(
        1 => 'Jan',
        2 => 'Feb',
        3 => 'Mar',
        4 => 'Apr',
        5 => 'May',
        6 => 'Jun',
        7 => 'Jul',
        8 => 'Aug',
        9 => 'Sep',
       10 => 'Oct',
       11 => 'Nov',
       12 => 'Dec'));
```

also, there is a special treatment to `boolean` types in ATK4 Models and does not directly correspond to the same **boolean** type in MySQL which is simply equivalent to TINYINT(1).

in order to make use of a type `boolean` for a table field in ATK4, it has to be declared as an `enum('Y','N')` and prepended with an `is_` on its field name.

example:

```
 CREATE TABLE foo (
 id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 :
 is_active ENUM('Y','N') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Y',
 :
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
 ) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

with this, the MVCGrid, MVCForm and CRUD can treat the `is_active` as a special field and be displayed as a graphical check mark on grids and a check box button on forms.

Answer (score 0):

The best source for types of fields that I have found is here:

[ATK4 API Reference](http://agiletoolkit.org/doc/ref)

Of course, I am less that a month into ATK4 and is a good starting point. The examples supplied with ATK4 are helpful and the Jobeet example has some good info. Dive in!